# Determine the ODBC connection in an access database

Tags: ms-access, odbc

Where do i find the odbc name that an access system is trying to use.

I have reached the limits of my access skills - ugh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a few ways - you don't mention what version.

but, you can "hover" your cursor over a linked table like this:

[image]

Or, hit-ctrl-g (jump to debug window).

and you can type in this:

? currentdb.TableDefs("dbo_HotelView").Connect

OutPut:

```
ODBC;DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER=albertkallal-pc\SQLEXPRESS;
Trusted_Connection=Yes;
APP=Microsoft Office 2010;
DATABASE=test3;
Network=DBMSSOCN;MultiSubnetFailover=Yes;
ConnectRetryCount=0;ConnectRetryInterval=5;
```

So, you do have to type in a "known" table link.

You can also right click on a linked table - choose design. (ignore the read only message). You see the table columns, and right click, choose properties (if not already displayed). And you see this:

[image]

I am trying to think of a few more ways (there are), but the above is a good start.